# Как дождаться создания объекта в другом потоке для вызова деструктора?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Необходимо иметь возможность создать объект в другом потоке и затем удалить в любое время (для асинхронного создания и перехода в машине состояний). Вызывается конструктор в другом потоке, в это время основной поток пытается вызвать деструктор, но до создания объект не удалятся.
Этот код, к сожалению, не работает. Деструктор вовсе не вызывается и Visual Leak Detector находит утечку памяти:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class Ex
{
private:

    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::string m_str;

public:

    Ex(const std::string& str) :
        m_str(str)
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(m_mutex);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << "Ex constructed!\n";
    }

    const std::string& get() const
    {
        return m_str;
    }

    ~Ex()
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(m_mutex);
        std::cout << "Ex destructed!" << " m_str = " << m_str << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Ex> ptr;
        std::thread thread([&]
            {
                ptr = std::make_unique<Ex>("string");
            });
        thread.detach();
    }

    std::getchar();
}
```

Comment: В этой схеме `ptr` может быть разрушен до того, как поток стартанет и попытается что-то с ним сделать, оставляя поток с битой ссылкой.

Comment: Спасибо, я пока плохо разбираюсь в многопоточности.  А если использовать shared_ptr и скопировать в функцию потока - то после выхода из потока он сам правильно удалится?

Comment: Если скопировать `shader_ptr` в поток, то получите два разных `shared_ptr`. По сути будет то же самое, как если бы просто создать внутри потока локальную переменную.

Comment: С++ запрещает что либо делать с объектом до того как его конструирование завершено. Объясните что вы хотите сделать без использования слов конструктор/деструктор. Какой должен быть эффект?

Comment: Кресты вместе с threads -- гремучая смесь. На практике (не в студенческих примерах, а в реальных вещах) работать не будет. (вообще, потоки нормально работают только с локальными данными (ну, локальными в том смысле, что в разделяемой между ними памяти каждому заранее распланированы его участки))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь я наконец-то понял, зачем использовать std::future и возвращать значения из потока. Думаю, это идеальное решение, ведь при "внезапном" уничтожении срабатывает функция wait(), то есть главный поток гарантированно дождётся побочного. К тому же, нет возни с исключениями в потоке:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Ex> ptr;
    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async,
        []
        {
            return std::make_shared<Ex>("Hello world!");
        });
    ptr = future.get();
    std::getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за помощь!
Было наивно полагать, что мьютекс объекта умного указателя будет распространятся на сам умный указатель.
Если я правильно понял, std::shared_ptr использует атомарный подсчёт ссылок и будет правильно удалён в зависимости от того, какой поток последним вызовет его деструктор:

```
std::shared_ptr<Ex> ptr;
std::thread thread([](std::shared_ptr<Ex> p)
    {
        p = std::make_shared<Ex>("string");
    }, ptr);
thread.detach();
```

Теперь единственная ошибка, которая может произойти - при выходе из программы отсоединённый поток будет просто уничтожен и ресурсы не будут правильно освобождены.

PS: Если кто-то набрёл на этот ответ: он неверный.

Comment: Этот код по-прежнему не работает. `ptr` в основном потоке никак не модифицируется. Копирование пустого указателя в поток бесполезно. *"будет правильно удалён в зависимости от того, какой поток последним вызовет его деструктор"* - главный поток вызовет деструктор объекта `ptr`, а созданный поток - деструктор **другого** объекта - деструктор аргумента (локальной переменной) `p` и деструктор объекта-копии `ptr`. Атомарный подсчёт ссылок используется для объекта, которым владеет `shader_ptr`.

Comment: Если я дождусь загрузки объекта в потоке, разве я не смогу его использовать или копировать в основном потоке? Для этого я могу добавить атомарный флаг проверки в функцию потока.

Comment: ¿Вы же осознаете, что при выполнении `p = std::make_shared<Ex>("string");` объект `ptr` в главном потоке не изменяется? Вообще для начала следует избавиться от `thread.detach();` (это практически всегда грубая ошибка) и от `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Что-то я всё равно не понимаю. При копировании одного shared_ptr в другой доступ к одному и тому же "состоянию" (или nullptr) остаётся в независимости от того, в каком потоке они изменяются. Мне необходимо вызвать некий объект асинхронно, но если случится так, что состояние ещё не загрузилось, а я уже использую другое, оно спокойно себе загрузилось и сразу же выгрузилось.

Comment: Ну так `ptr` в главном потоке как был с nullptr, так с ним и останется. А что делается с его копиями в новом потоке - не важно. Вообще вам стоит нормально поставить задачу, т.е. написать в коде assert для требуемого поведения.

Answer (score 0):

Разве этот код:

```
std::shared_ptr<Ex> ptr = std::make_shared<Ex>("string");
stateMachine.append(ptr);
```

Не будет работать аналогичным образом с этим?

```
    std::shared_ptr<Ex> ptr;
    std::shared_ptr <std::atomic<bool>> flag = std::make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(false);
    std::thread thread([&](std::shared_ptr<Ex> p, std::shared_ptr <std::atomic<bool>>)
        {
            p = std::make_shared<Ex>("string");
            flag->store(true);
        }, ptr, flag);
    thread.detach();

    while (!flag->load())
    {
    }

    stateMachine.append(ptr);
```

PS: я проверил - действительно не работает. Потому что я перезаписываю умный указатель. Спасибо за помощь - буду уже самостоятельно подробно изучать как всё это работает.